# Is it possible to use Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.dll in x64?

Tags: 64-bit, expression, screen, record, encoder

I would like to capture the screen by using Microsoft Expression.
I read that EE4 SDK is x86 (32-bit) only.

Is there anyway to use Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.dll in x64??

My error is;

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Expression.Encoder,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0):

Download the file named **Microsoft Expression Encoder** & Install it. Then try to run your application.